# Prevent other applications from connecting to your TcpListener

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ftp

I made a FTP server application which uses Net's sockets. The application will immediately disconnect a client, that was accepted by the TcpListener, if the client didn't send a login message containing a username and password. But how do I prevent someone from decompiling my client application and seeing the server's password and replicating the message that's required by the client, to login in to the server, in another app. In general I want to avoid someone from making an application, that implements my objects from the .dll provided with the client application, which can connect to my FTP server.

Comment: Don't hardcode passwords and/or use encryption?

Comment: @Kinetic, How would I then go to request login permission from the server that requires a password? If I would encrypt a password, someone can easily just decrypt the password by either decompiling my application to get the algorithm or fake an authentication message to request the key from the server to decrypt the password? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to completely protect your service if you are going to distribute a client library. As Kinetic says, hard coding passwords is definitely a bad idea because someone could easily decompile your assembly or use something like process explorer to discover it.

There is usually little harm in gracefully handling any client that conforms to your protocol. If you think that it's likely your service will be the subject of abuse then perhaps look into denial of service protection.